# What causes the error "kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin Could not load module <Error module>" in gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

what is causing the error?, I've been searching for hours but nothing worked, and also the error message given is incomplete

I have tried

- Invalidate cache and restart
- reinstall gradle and android studio

but nothing worked
[image]